# sprite is not moving down

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, move

I do not know how to create new sprites by mouse click and add a movement to all new sprites.

I have created a simple game:

- Diamond : move left/right with `K_LEFT`, `K_RIGHT`
- Pad: move left/right with mouse

if you click a mouse you append hearts and draw a sprite heart0, heart1, etc. according to number of mouse clicks.

if you click a mouse you draw a sprite heart which drops in place where the diamond is and heart should move down...

PROBLEM: hearts are not moving down. I can not draw multiple hearts. 
At the moment I can only draw a heart in a place where the diamon is and append hearts.

Do you know what is wrong with my code so I can not get required functionality please ?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 640
screen_height = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 15)

hearts = [] 
clicks = []

class HeartSprite(object):

    def __init__(self, pozx, pozy):

        self.image = pygame.image.load("heart.png")
        self.posx = pozx
        self.posy = pozy   
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.going_down = True
        self.next_update_time = 0

    def update(self, current_time, bottom):
        if self.next_update_time < current_time:
            ### bounce back
            #if self.rect.bottom >= bottom - 1:
            #    self.going_down = False
            ### kill it
            if self.posy > screen_height:
                del hearts[0]
            elif self.posy <= 85:
                self.going_down = True       
            if self.going_down:
                self.posy += 2
            else:
                self.posy -= 2
            self.next_update_time = current_time + 10

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.posx, self.posy))

class Diamond(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("diamond.png").convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 3
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect[0] -= dist
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect[0] += dist

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect[0], self.rect[1]+18))

class Pad(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load("pad.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.top = screen.get_height() - self.rect[1]
        self.shoot_y = 0
        self.shoot_x = 0
    def draw(self, surface, posx, posy):
        surface.blit(self.image, (posx, posy))

class DisplayText(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Tahoma", 15)
        self.heartsleft = 10 - len(hearts)
        self.label = self.myfont.render("hearts left : %d" %     self.heartsleft, 1, (0,0,0))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.label, (3, 1))

def main():

    diamond = Diamond()   
    pad = Pad()

    while True:

        white = (255, 255, 255)
        screen.fill(white)
        time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pad.draw(screen, x - pad.rect[2]/2, screen_height - pad.rect[2]/2 )

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                diamondy = diamond.rect[1]+18
                diamondx = diamond.rect[0]
                count = "clicks"
                clicks.append(count)
                myvar = len(clicks)
                for i in range(myvar):
                    ii = "heart" + str(i)
                hearts.append(ii)

        for myfigure in hearts:
            myfigure = HeartSprite(diamondx , diamondy)
            myfigure.update(time, 480)
            myfigure.draw(screen)

        diamond.draw(screen)   
        diamond.handle_keys()

        displaytext = DisplayText()
        displaytext.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()              
        clock.tick(100)
    pygame.quit()
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this loop:

```
for myfigure in hearts:
    myfigure = HeartSprite(diamondx , diamondy)
    myfigure.update(time, 480)
    myfigure.draw(screen)
```

Stop a moment and think of what this loop really does. It creates a new instance of `HeartSprite` with `diamondx` and `diamondy` for each element in hearts; every time the loop is run.

What you really want to do is to create the `HeartSprite` instances once you click on the screen, and keep those instances in the list (so each heart keeps its state):

```
...
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            diamondy = diamond.rect[1]+18
            diamondx = diamond.rect[0]
            hearts.append(diamondx, diamondy)
...
    for myfigure in hearts:
        myfigure.update(time, 480)
        myfigure.draw(screen)
...
```

---

There are some more issues with this code, but that's out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to move forward. I will think more about the problem before I place the code and ask for help.